# Split string on an unknown integer plus a substring

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split a very large string into pieces. However, the format is not very consistent. Therefore, I want to have some flexibility in the characters I'm splitting on.

As an example:

"This is a string I would like to split **0 here** but I also want it to split **2 here** to end up with 3 strings."

So my delimiter format is `int + 'here'`.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for such type of problems like,

```
import re
s = 'This is a string I would like to split 0 here but I also want it to split 2 here to end up with 3 strings.'
re.split(r'\d+\s*here', s)
# Output as : ['This is a string I would like to split ',
#' but I also want it to split ',
#' to end up with 3 strings.']
```

Comment: `\d+\s+here\b` then else space is optional and will match 100here (if it matters...) and also take account of word boundary.